# XML conflict from PHP to Chrome browser with empty elements

Tags: php, html, xml, browser

Let's pick this XML fragment that should result in HTML:

```
<login status="not">
    <usr>
        <html layout="mobile">
            <div id="loginUsrBox"> </div>
             <div style="text-align:center"><button onclick="usrCadPainel('cadastrar'); painel(false);" class="button">Cadastrar</button>
             <button onclick="usrCadPainel('filiar'); painel(false);" class="button">Filiar</button></div>
        </html>
        <html layout="desktop">
            Bem vindo! <span id="loginUsrBox"> </span>
             <button onclick="usrCadPainel('cadastrar'); painel(false);" class="button">Cadastrar</button>
             <button onclick="usrCadPainel('filiar'); painel(false);" class="button">Quero Me Filiar</button>
        </html>
    </usr>
</login>
```

The DIV and also SPAN elements with `id="loginUsrBox"` have one space between open and close tags. This will be used by a JavaScript to show user content. If I don't put those spaces, the result will be, for instance, from `<div id="loginUsrBox"></div>` to `<div id="loginUsrBox"/>` when the PHP lib parse from the file to a XML object and than to text XML by `->asXML()` method.

Then, when the XML now as HTML is put in place in the page, Chrome will consider the tag as an error and to add a closing tag  at the end of all. The result is the buttons inside of the DIV and will be overwritten by the JavaScript to show user info (in this case, just the info - not logged in).

It's in fact an easy to avoid issue with that space, but I am also thinking about a more "intense" use of this library and show content in Chrome (don't know if it will fail in other browsers). Let's imagine dynamic created XML, will I have to code some workaround? Is there some official way to deal with this?

EDIT: have tested in Firefox. Same result, the tag  won't be recognized as . As a correction, at the end of the upper element a tag  will be add by the browser's renderer. So next sibling elements will be moved to inside  tag.

Comment: I’m not really sure of your question. Why are you trying to treat HTML as XML in the first place? XHTML was ultimately abandoned by the standards groups for HTML5

Comment: Don't use `asXML` then, use `asHTML`?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Is the opposite, I have many snippets HTML in a XML "database". I will pick the one I need and to add in a page as HTML. Not using XHTML. To store HTML snippets en JSON is possible, but also tricky.

Comment: @CBroe There is no "asHTML" method in SimpleXML library. Maybe I should make it...

Comment: @Gustavo, the usage of SimpleXML was missing from your question, I was thinking you were using `DOMDocument`. Are you storing the XML with self-closing tags already, or is it SimpleXML that is doing that for you. My recommendation would be to run whatever you do through an HTML-aware thing, whatever that may be.

Comment: @ChrisHaas SimpleXML is creating the self-closing tags. When I did read your comment, I stopped for a while to research more about the subject. I am a bit confuse because XML, to me, was the basics for all, including HTML and DOMDocument, that should accept all XML syntax. But it seems is not like that. I will make an answer to my own question later, trying to clarify the problems.

Comment: HTML predates XML by a couple of years, however both were/are related to SGML which is much older, and why they look similar (specifically the ML). XHTML was an attempt to align HTML with XML back when XML was getting really cool, however that was eventually dropped, although self-closing tags are still allowed in HTML5 for compatibility reasons. HTML5 is no longer based on SGML, but to the best of my knowledge, still has an XML serialization format. Because of all of this, that's why I'd recommend using an HTML-aware parser.

Answer (score 0):

After solve the problem, I decided to change the technique. So here is how I see this problem.

First, HTML and XML are good friends but are parallel technologies as long the PHP documentation mention XML in DOMDocument part - in fact, is inside XML manipulation section. But after research a few, I came to the conclusion that it's better think as similar technologies.

That said, browsers interpreters will not accept self-closing tags that are not in the list: "area", "base", "br", "col", "embed", "hr", "img", "input", "link", "meta", "param", "source", "track", "wbr". So to keep in the SimpleXML field, a syntax corrector will be needed to actually pick the needed piece and to put in the page:

```
function convertSelfClosingTags($html) {
$newhtml = $html;
$Not = ["area","base","br","col","embed","hr","img","input","link","meta","param","source","track","wbr"];
preg_match_all("/<[^>]+?\/>/", $html, $Tags, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
foreach($Tags[0] as $Tag) {
    $Info = [];
    $Doc = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
    $Doc->loadHTML($Tag[0]);
    error_log("convertSelfClosingTags DOMDocument...\n".$Doc->saveHTML());
    $DocBody = $Doc->getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    $DocElem = $DocBody->firstChild;
    $Info["name"] = $DocElem->localName;
    if(!in_array($Info["name"], $Not)) {
        $Info["tag"] = $Tag[0];
        $Info["size"] = strlen($Tag[0]);
        $Info["offset"] = $Tag[1];
        $newtag = '<'.$Info["name"];
        if($DocElem->hasAttributes()) {
            $Attrs = $DocElem->attributes;
            foreach($Attrs as $key=>$value) {
                $newtag .= ' '.$key.'="'.$value->value.'"';
            }
        }
        $newtag .= '></'.$Info["name"].'>';
        $newhtml = str_replace($Info["tag"], $newtag, $newhtml);
    }
    //error_log("convertSelfClosingTags newtag: ".$newtag);
}
return $newhtml;
}
```

This will get the substring of the XML generated by SimpleXML library and make it HTML friendly.

But, as commented in the question, why not to work with HTML in the first place? So I have converted the XML file to a HTML 4.0 and changed all my PHP code to work with HTML. Hours studying DOMDocument class and all classes involved, plus hours to get the code done. And there is some issues either.

So by using XML that is better for a simple database, the final string will have to be corrected to be HTML friendly. By using HTML, the code will be more tricky and the tags, attributes and specially id attributes must be HTML friendly (id must be unique).

An important observation: DOMDocument library works with HTML 4.0. If you need to work with HTML5, you will need a third part library as this one: [html5lib](https://github.com/html5lib)

In my case, some id attributes are labeled as "id_" and will be replaced to "id" after I take the piece I need. See the example:

```
        <div class="usr" public="def">
            <div layout="mobile">
                <div id_="loginUsrBox">...</div>
                 <button onclick="usrCadPainel('filiar'); painel(false);">Quero Me Filiar</button>
             </div>
            <div layout="desktop">
                Bem vindo! <span id_="loginUsrBox">...</span>
                 <button onclick="usrCadPainel('filiar'); painel(false);" class="button">Quero Me Filiar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have two layouts and will pick just one. But because I am storing both in HTML, the id "loginUsrBox" is id_.

That's it, my dear coders, no easy solution!